# Android Default String Resource: Why android.R.string.yes is getting OK

Tags: android, string, android-resources

I am trying to display the default string from the String Resources of Android.

**My Code Snippet:**

```
    new AlertDialog.Builder(CartProductListActivity.this)
            .setTitle("Are you sure?")
            .setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this item from cart?")
            .setPositiveButton(getString(android.R.string.yes), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(getString(android.R.string.no), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }).show();
```

In the above code, I have used `android.R.string.yes` and `android.R.string.no` which is returning **OK** and **Cancel** respectively.

I show default string.xml file by <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + clicking on that `yes` and That has a same string (for `yes` and `ok`) as below:

```
<!-- Preference framework strings. -->
<string name="ok">OK</string>
<!-- Preference framework strings. -->
<string name="cancel">Cancel</string>
<!-- Preference framework strings. -->
<string name="yes">OK</string>
<!-- Preference framework strings. -->
<string name="no">Cancel</string>
```

Why there are two resources with same name. User is getting confused for `yes`? Is it a bug of Android Default Resources?

> Why `android.R.string.yes` don't have value as `Yes`?
>
> Why `android.R.string.no` don't have value as `No`?

Note: I saw there is **android.R.string.yes => YES** but why its changed now?

Comment: well, `no` also returns `cancel` according to what you've shown there

Comment: I'm not properly getting you but `string.xml` not allow same `name`.

Comment: Can you please specify what is the error that you are facing? Both "no" and "cancel" are having the same value.

Comment: @Pronoy999 that's the point of this question. the resources are defined by android and they have the same values internally, the value for `yes` is `OK`, where you would expect it to be `OK`, OP is asking if it's a bug with android or why it happens to be like that

Comment: @a_local_nobody I want `YES` as a string. My question is why there are two resources with same name. User is getting confused for `yes`

Comment: @Pronoy999 you got my point.

Comment: @PratikButani There is not a same name there is only same value. And i already told you `string.xml` grant same `value` but if you define same `name` then error accrue.

Comment: @Ali My question is, Why the same value. Is it a bug? error? or Mistake? by Android. Why `android.R.string.yes` don't have value `Yes`

Comment: Did you add third party libraries? They can also affect your string res.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43694575/is-it-possible-to-override-android-string-resource-from-external-aar-library

Comment: No, I am using that string from resources of `Android api-29` @MartinPfeffer

Comment: Just create your own string `R.string.yes` with value `yes`.
Don't use `android.R.string.yes`

Comment: @RaymondChenon Many Thanks. I already know this thing. I just wanted to know why Android declares two or more resources with the same value.

Comment: As others wrote two strings have the same value. I learnt it too through the comments

Comment: My best guess is that those resources are there for **backward compatibility**. Older Android versions and or frameworks probably use one set and newer the other set. To cover both cases they need to be there even though they have the same value.

Comment: no and yes seems to be deprecated, i.e. they don't want yes and no printed in dialogs everywhere, but want to encourage OK and Cancel for the same purpose. Hence they just remapped those values in later version.